# How to return an async array from Express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module, backend

[I am trying to pass my getAll() method of the Container class, and show the objects that are in the products.txt file, however when I try to show it by the page path by express in res.send() it shows me only a empty object, but in the console it shows me the respective products that are in products.txt, it's like I can't find a way to show those objects in the browser, the method is asynchronous so it must be because of that, but no I find a way to fix it]

[app.js]

```
const fs = require("fs");

class Contenedor {
  constructor(txtNameFile) {
    this.txtNameFile = txtNameFile;
    this.products = [];
  }

  async fileInJSON() {
    let fileTxt = await fs.promises.readFile(this.txtNameFile, "utf-8");
    let type = JSON.parse(fileTxt);
    return type;
  }

  async fileSaving(item) {
    let type = JSON.stringify(item);
    await fs.promises.writeFile(this.txtNameFile, type);
  }

  async save(obj) {
    try {
      let fileTxt = await fs.promises.readFile(this.txtNameFile, "utf-8");
      if (fileTxt === "") {
        obj.id = 1;
        this.products.push(obj);
      } else {
        const type = JSON.parse(fileTxt);
        obj.id = type[type.length - 1].id + 1;
        type.push(obj);
        this.products = type;
        this.fileSaving(type);
      }
      console.log(
        "El producto se ha guardado en el archivo satisfactoriamente"
      );
      return obj.id;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("No se ha podido guardar");
    }
  }

  async getById(id) {
    let type = await this.fileInJSON();
    let product = type.find((product) => product.id == id);
    return console.log(product);
  }

  async getAll() {
    let type = await this.fileInJSON();
    return console.log(type);
  }

  async deleteAll() {
    let item = [];
    this.products = item;
    this.fileSaving(item);
  }

  async deleteById(number) {
    let type = await this.fileInJSON();
    let item = type.find((item) => item.id === number);
    let index = type.indexOf(item);
    type.splice(index, 1);
    this.fileSaving(type);
  }
}

module.exports = Contenedor;
```

[appServer.js]

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const Contenedor = require("./app.js");
const newShoeProduct = new Contenedor("./products.txt");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Ingresa a la ruta /productos para ver los productos :D");
});

app.get("/productos", (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(newShoeProduct.getAll()));
});

console.log(newShoeProduct);
 

const servidor = app
  .listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor corriendo en el puerto ${PORT}`);
  })
  .on("error", (error) => console.error("FALLASTE" + error));
```

[products.txt]

```
[{"title":"Zapatillas Volcom urbanas","price":3000,"thumbnail":"https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_938726-MLA31099290226_062019-O.webp","id":1},{"title":"Zapatillas DC dark","price":2100,"thumbnail":"https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_737014-MLA41571053814_042020-O.webp","id":2},{"title":"Zapatillas Adidas deportivas","price":1500,"thumbnail":"https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_771197-MLA49179920702_022022-O.webp","id":3} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called async functions but not waited for the first in the call chain. This should resolve your problem:

```
app.get("/productos", async (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(await newShoeProduct.getAll()));
});
```

Notice the missing `await` for getAll() as that function is also async

Comment: You should add ‘async‘ to te function.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! They are very helpful, but I still can't see the objects of products.txt in the /products route, after implementing that I no longer see an empty object, now I only see the entire page blank, and no error is returned

Comment: @Nacho you haven't added any UI code. It might help to share that as well. Even on the UI you need to make sure you either `await` the call or use `.then()`

Comment: when I do console.log(newShoeProduct) this is what I get back Contenedor { txtNameFile: './products.txt', products: [] }

Comment: This `Contenedor { txtNameFile: './products.txt', products: [] }` is exactly how you have initialized it in your constructor. Looks like it's not changing at all after initialization

Comment: You return `console.log()` instead of returning actual values from those functions, why would you do that ? `getAll` calls `fileInJson` which simply reads the file and parses it, why are you calling the result `type` ? If that's a list of products, call that `products` and just return them, or do `this.products = ...` and return the instance products value in the response.